# Will a dwarf fight better with a weapon that he likes?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I have a dwarf who is a competent axedwarf but 'likes' shields and spears-- do I ignore the relatively modest experience he already has with axes and put him in with my 300-esque, large-monster-taker-downer-er..ers.. or, do I just ignore that and make him an axedwarf?

Comment: I think it just adds to his mood and he probably gets attached to a spear sooner.

Comment: I kinda wanted this to be true =[ but tbh I didn't know about this for a long while after I started playing: dwarves will make higher quality items if it's a) an item they like or b) made out of a material they like. The effect is cumulative, with a dwarf who likes steel and spears making a better steel spear on average than a dwarf who likes either steel or spears.

Answer (score 1):

As far as everybody knows, the three main effects of preferences are

1. Happy thoughts for that item/material
2. Higher quality when manufacturing that particular thing (so if you've got a starting dwarf that likes silver and warhammers, put him as your weaponsmith)
3. Higher chance of making that item when in fey mood.

There have been no tests shown to have any difference in combat - it might be interesting to try it in the arena, x dwarves loving their weapon type versus identical dwarves liking something else.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, but they will get mood boosts from having an item they like.